# CONFLICT WITH INSTALLING OPENCV 2.4.2

Tags: opencv, installation

I downloaded OpenCV-2.4.2 and I couldn't find any exe(auto run) file there.How ever I extracted that in to my C:\ directory and followed the following process in this video>> 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgo0UitHfp8&feature=plcp

I have VS 2008 version. According to the video first I Added OpenCV to system variables and next build Visual Studio project. Added all the libraries and completed according to the video.

But When I debug my project it says>>
The application has failed to start because tbb_debug.dll was not found.

So;

1)Are there any wrong in my installation or this video?

2)Did I completed the installation process correct?

I must be thankful to u if u reply this soon.

Thank U

Answer (score 0):

You are missing tbb_debug.dll (or it's not in your path)
If you built (or downloaded) opencv with TBB enabled then you need to install [tbb](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/file.php?fid=77) and then put tbb.dll and tbb_debug.dll on the path (eg. copy to the opencv bin folder)

Comment: But when we install opencv by Using the Pre-built Libraries do we need to install TBB manually? It is not in hear>> http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation I followed all the steps in this tutorial but it is mentioned regarding TBB; installation by making our Own Libraries from the Source Files. So hear I totally conflicted. Could u please be kind enough to mention the steps which should I follow to install OpenCV2.4.2 using pre-built libraries. Thanks..

Comment: I normally build from source, but if your pre-built is buitl to use TBB you need TBB. I suspect the license doesn't allow it to be included - so you have to get it separately from Intel, it's a free download of the dll.